# OBS stream to meeting on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, stream, obs, meeting-request

with everything being online these days, I am looking to improve my lectures for students by making use of OBS (Open Broadcasting Software) on a Linux (Ubuntu 20) platform.

Ideally, I would like to redirect the normal streaming/recording of OBS to a virtual microphone and a virtual camera as to turn any conference environment (Google, Zoom, Jitsi, Teams, etc.) into something that works like Twitch or Youtube.

On Windows, it seems to be possible to use the [OBS-VirtualCam](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-virtualcam.949/) plugin. Although there is a Linux version of this plugin, it only seems to support video and not audio.

Any ideas on how to best achieve this? The guides and posts I found so far online did not seem to be very successful on including audio.

Answer (score 1):

The virtual camera is transmitted with rather low resolution by some conference systems, so even on windows this will not be a great experience.

What I do instead is to open a full screen or window projector (in OBS studio, right click on the scene preview and select "windowed projector" or "full screen projector") and screen share that window from the conferencing software. This will result in much better resolution.

It doesn't transmit sound, though, so you still have to select the appropriate mic in your conferencing software.

[image]